# Why does the following algorithm have runtime log(log(n))?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime, big-o, logarithm

I don't understand how the runtime of the algorithm can be `log(log(n))`. Can someone help me?

```py
s=1
while s <= (log n)^2 do
     s=3s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notation note: `log(n)` indicates `log2(n)` throughout the solution.

Well, I suppose `(log n)^2` indicates the square of `log(n)`, which means `log(n)`*`log(n)`. Let us try to analyze the algorithm.
It starts from `s`=1 and goes like 1,3,9,27...

Since it goes by the exponents of 3, after each iteration `s` can be shown as `3^m`, `m` being the number of iterations starting from 1.

We will do these iterations until `s` becomes bigger than `log(n)`*`log(n)`. So at some point `3^m` will be equal to `log(n)*log(n)`. 
Solve the equation: 
`3^m = log(n) * log(n)`
`m` = `log3(log(n) * log(n))`
Time complexity of the algorithm can be shown as `O(m)`. We have to express `m` in terms of `n`. 
`log3(log(n) * log(n))` = `log3(log(n))` + `log3(log(n))`

= `2 * log3(log(n))`  For Big-Oh notation, constants do not matter. So let us get rid of 2.

Time complexity = `O(log3(log(n)))`

 Well ok, here is the deal: By the definition of Big-Oh notation, it represents an **upper bound** runtime for our function. Therefore `O(n) ⊆ O(n^2)`. 
Notice that `log3(a)` < `log2(a)` after a point. 
By the same logic we can conclude that `O(log3(log(n)) ⊆ O(log(log(n))`.

So the time complexity of the algorithm : `O(log(logn))`

Not the most scientific explanation, but I hope you got the point.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This follows as a special case of a more general principle. Consider the following loop:

```
s = 1
while s < k:
    s = 3s
```

How many times will this loop run? Well, the values of s taken on will be equal to 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, ... = 3<sup>0</sup>, 3<sup>1</sup>, 3<sup>2</sup>, 3<sup>3</sup>, ... . And more generally, on the ith iteration of the loop, the value of s will be 3<sup>i</sup>.

This loop stops running at soon as 3<sup>i</sup> overshoots k. To figure out where that is, we can equate and solve:

> 3<sup>i</sup> = k
>
> i = log<sub>3</sub> k

So this loop will run a total of log<sub>3</sub> k times.

Now, what do you think would happen if we used this loop instead?

```
s = 1
while s < k:
    s = 4s
```

Using similar logic, the number of loop iterations would be log<sub>4</sub> k. And more generally, if we have the following loop:

```
s = 1
while s < k:
    s = c * s
```

Then assuming c > 1, the number of iterations will be log<sub>c</sub> k.

Given this, let's look at your loop:

```
s = 1
while s <= (log n)^2 do
     s = 3s
```

Using the reasoning from above, the number of iterations of this loop works out to log<sub>3</sub> (log n)<sup>2</sup>. Using properties of logarithms, we can simplify this to

> log<sub>3</sub> (log n)<sup>2</sup>
>
> = 2 log<sub>3</sub> log n
>
> = **O(log log n)**.